# Problem solving: How far is the maximum distance?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, problem-solving

The tires located on the front of the car wears out after $25000$ km, while the tires on the back wears out after $15000$ km. How far can you maximum ride with new tires if you can swap the tires during the journey?

Comment: No, how long distance you can travel if you have the ability to swap. Notice that all the tires are the same and hold from the same amount of time, it depends where the tires are put.

Comment: Try calculate it you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly each pair of tires will spend the same distance $d$ front and rear.  During the time they are on the front, they will use up $\frac d{25000}$ of their life.  On the rear, they will use up $\frac d{15000}$ of their life, so $\frac d{25000}+\frac d{15000}=1$